# Using C++ to receive int inputs and displaying the larger and smaller number

Tags: c++

The instructions are to

1. Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating 'I' is entered.
2. Change the program to write out the smaller value is: followed by the smaller of the nwnbers and the larger value is: followed by the larger value.

I got the program to run but it terminates with a Range error: Can anybody correct my mistake in this code?

```
/*a drill in the Programming Principles
and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup*/
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"     /*standard library from the author's website*/
int main()
{
    vector<int>values;
    int a, b;       //ints declared
    while(cin>>a>>b){   //ints read
        values.push_back(a);    //ints put into vector
        values.push_back(b);    //********************
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i){     //loop
        if(values[i]>values[i+1]){
            cout << "The larger value is: " << values[i] << endl;   /*print larger value on screen*/
        }
        else
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << values[i] << endl;  /*prints smaller value on screen*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: BTW, your algo prints each number, not only the smallest/biggest. `std::minmax_element` would solve the whole exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values[i+1]` goes out of bounds for the last value, so you need to change your `for` loop condition

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; ++i){ 
                              // ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around
    the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program
    when a terminating 'I' is entered.

```
int a, b = 0; 
//  anything that isn't a int terminate the input e.g. 2 3 |
while (cin >> a >> b)  
  cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
```

2.Change the program to write out the smaller value is: followed by the smaller of the nwnbers and the larger value is: followed by the larger value.

```
int a, b;
const string smaller = "smaller value is: ";
const string larger = "larger value is: ";

while (cin >> a >> b) {
    if (a < b)
        cout << smaller << a << larger << b << endl;
    else
        cout << smaller << b << larger << a << endl;
} 

if (cin.fail()) {
    cin.clear();
    char ch;
    if (!(cin >> ch && ch == '|'))
        throw runtime_error(string {"Bad termination"});
}
```